# Copy correctly the inner area of contour in OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using opencv and python, I'm trying to detect some game cards and
I'm stuck. I want to copy the inner area of countor. I've wrote this code:

**DETECT THE CONTOURS**

```py
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    image = frame of a video
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (1, 1), 1000)
    flag, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

    contourns_to_draw = []

    # filter the cards contour
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        card = contours[i]
        peri = cv2.arcLength(card, True)
        if (peri > 150) and (not is_in_array(card, contourns_to_draw)):
            rect = cv2.boundingRect(card)
            x, y, w, h = rect
            if h > w:
                contourns_to_draw.append(card)

    img = cv2.drawContours(image, contourns_to_draw, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
```

**COPY THE AREA OF THE CONTOURS AND CREATE A NEW IMAGE**

```py
for i, contour in enumerate(contourns_to_draw):
        peri = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)

        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.01 * peri, True)

        h = np.array([[0, 0], [449, 0], [449, 449], [0, 449]], np.float32)

        if  len(approx) != 4 :
            continue
        else:
            transform = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(approx.astype(np.float32), h)


        warp = cv2.warpPerspective(image, transform, (450, 450))
        # warp = rotateImage(warp, -90)
        warp = cv2.flip(warp, +1)

        dominance_color = bincount_app(warp)
        cv2.imshow("Show Boxes", warp)
        key = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
```

When i use this code on the the frames of a video like this one

[image]

The contour detection works fine but when it creates a new image from the contour area the output is a new image with random rotation and sometimes flipped too

**EXAMPLE OF CONTOUR INNER AREA IMAGE**
[image]

my objective is to have an image that has no rotation and that is not flipped, sometimes the output is correct but other times is something like the image that i added, I don't understant what generate the difference in the outputs.

Comment: Maybe the `cv2.approxPolyDP` is not returning the points in the required order which is top_left, bottom_left, bottom_right, top_right. Try reordering the points you receive from `cv2.approxPolyDP`

Comment: How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV assumes that first vertex of a contour is closest to the upper edge of the image. So depends on camera orientation it may lead to the effect that you've shown. In your case you should rearrange vertices in `approx`. See [this link for details](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/21/ordering-coordinates-clockwise-with-python-and-opencv/).